# Getting Json data from another domain, within a proxy servlet

Tags: json, gwt, servlets

I'm working on a GWT project, in which I have to fetch some JSON data from a real web-domain. Due to SOP policy, GWT fails to get those data.

To address this, as suggested in [GWT docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html#design), I have created some proxy servlets within GWT, which in turn should call the actual JSON provider external url.

Does anybody know how should I retrieve json data from an external url, within a servlet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/data.json").openStream();
```

#### See also:

- [How to fire and handle HTTP requests using URLConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)